# java web app - can't retrieve pages that are not from root folder

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

i work with Intellij-idea IDE and tomcat. i tried to retrieve pages that are inside 
folders in my web-inf and got HTTP error 404. however i can only retrieve the page in the root folder.

what to do?

thanks.

Comment: show your relevant code

Comment: Show you code, project structure. How are you trying to access the pages?

Comment: Web-inf files are not meant to be accessed publicly. They mainly help in mapping of requests. You need to place them outside web-inf.

Comment: You cannot access resource in /web-inf/ directly from the browser.

Answer (score 2):

From the [servlet spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/), section 10.5 Directory structure (emphasis by me):

> A special directory exists within the application hierarchy named
>   “WEB-INF”. This directory contains all things related to the
>   application that aren’t in the document root of the application. Most
>   of the WEB-INF node is **not part of the public document tree of the
>   application**. Except for static resources and JSPs packaged in the
>   META- INF/resources of a JAR file that resides in the WEB-INF/lib
>   directory, **no other files contained in the WEB-INF directory may be
>   served directly to a client by the container**. However, the contents of
>   the WEB-INF directory are visible to servlet code using the
>   getResource and getResourceAsStream method calls on the
>   ServletContext, and may be exposed using the RequestDispatcher calls...

So, what you experience is "by design". Place your resources elsewhere if you need to request them through HTTP.